# microsoft learn minilab: Test hypothesis by simulating statistics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference

I'm taking a Microsoft Learn online course: [The Foundations of Datascience](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/foundations-data-science/)

Throughout, it has minilabs at the end of each module to test your understanding.

I am stuck on the "[Test hypothesis by simulating statistics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/test-hypothesis-by-simulating-statistics/)" module [minilab](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/test-hypothesis-by-simulating-statistics/05-mini-labs).

[EDIT]

Here is the minilab on Github:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/inferentialthinking/blob/master/minilabs/test-hypothesis-by-simulating-statistics/test_hypothesis_minilab.ipynb

"In the previous two labs we've analyzed some data regarding COVID-19 test cases. Let's continue to analyze this data, specifically claims about this data. Once again, we'll be be using ficitious statistics from Blockeley University."

"Let's say that Blockeley data science faculty are looking at the spread of COVID-19 across the realm of Minecraft. We have very specific data about Blockeley and the rest of Cubefornia but other realms' data isn't as clear cut or detailed. Let's say that a neighboring village has been reporting a COVID-19 infection rate of 26%. Should we trust these numbers?"

"Regardless of whether or not you believe these claims, the job of a data scientist is to definitively substantiate or disprove such claims using data. You have access to the test results of similar sized villages nearby and come up with the brilliant idea of running a hypothesis test. Let's go ahead and load it! Run the cell below to import this data. If you want to explore this data further, go ahead and group by both columns! An empty cell is provided for you to do this."

Here is the data for the activity:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/inferentialthinking/blob/master/minilabs/datasets/new_covid19_village_tests.csv

From the above link, Part 1 of the exercise proceeds as follows:

> From here we can formulate our Null Hypothesis and Alternate Hypothesis Our null hypothesis is that this village truly has a 26% infection rate amongst the populations. Our alternate hypothesis is that this village does not in actuality have a 26% infection rate - it's way too low. Now we need our test statistic. Since we're looking at the infection rate in the population, our test statistic should be given by the following formula:

$$\text{Test Statistic} = \frac{\text{Number of Positive Cases}}{\text{Total Number of Cases}}$$
We've started the function declaration for you. Go ahead and complete proportion_positive to calculate this test statistic.

Note: Check out np.count_nonzero and built-in len function! These should be helpful for you.

```
def proportion_positive(test_results):
numerator = ...
denominator = ...
return numerator / denominator
```

[END EDIT]

I wonder if anybody has seen this course and can give me the solution to the minilab.

After importing some fictitious Covid19 data, you are asked to determine a test statistic for the null hypothesis and the alternative hypothesis.

My best attempt at part 1 of the minilab is the following python:

```
test_results = Table.read_table("../datasets/covid19_village_tests.csv")

def proportion_positive(test_results):
    numerator = np.count_nonzero(test_results.column('Test Result') == 'positive')
    denominator = len(test_results.column('Test Result'))
    return numerator / denominator
```

It is not passing this result, and I don't really know what is going wrong.
Perhaps I have the wrong idea about how to define the test statistic.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't find which part of the course you're asking about from looking at your links. Can you describe the Covid data (variables? sample size? etc) and state the hypothesis you want to test?

Comment: Thanks @BruceET, I edited the question with a little more explanation and more links. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: You still mention the null hypothesis without telling, what the null hypothesis is.

Comment: @BruceET I have added a lot more explanation, data and links to the question, including the null hypothesis and the question code itself. Let me know if you have any suggestions or further questions.